# Function returning NaN when I try to generate basic math operations

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate randomly basic math operations(addition, subtractions, multiplication and  division) and sometime my function returns NaN.
    I used function parseInt(), but I still have the same problem. I will appreciate if anybody can help me with any suggestion.
    Thank you in advance!

```
Here is my code:

function randNum(min,max)
{
    var num = min+Math.floor((Math.random()*(max-min+1)));
    return num;
}

var choose, operator, firstNum, secondNum,rightAnswer;
function getProb()
{
    var chooseOp=randNum(1,4);
    choose=parseInt(chooseOp);

if (choose==1)
{
    oprator="+";
    var choose1=randNum(0,10);
    var choose2=randNum(0,10);
    firstNum=parseInt(choose1);
    secondNum=parseInt(choose2);
    document.getElementById("mathProb").innerHTML=firstNum+operator+secondNum+"=";
    rightAnswer=choose1 + choose2;
}
else if (choose==2)
{
    operator="-";
    var choose1=randNum(0,10);
    var choose2=randNum(0,10);
    firstNum=parseInt(choose1);
    secondNum=parseInt(choose2);
    document.getElementById("mathProb").innerHTML=firstNum+operator+secondNum+"=";
    rightAnswer=firstNum - secondNum;
}
else if (choose==3)
{
    operator="x";
    var choose1=randNum(0,10);
    var choose2=randNum(0,10);
    firstNum=parseInt(choose1);
    secondNum=parseInt(choose2);
    document.getElementById("mathProb").innerHTML=firstNum+operator+secondNum+"=";
    rightAnswer=choose1 * choose2;
}
    else if (choose==4)
{
    operator="/";
    var choose1=randNum(0,10);
    var choose2=randNum(0,10);
    firstNum=parseInt(choose1);
    secondNum=parseInt(choose2);
    document.getElementById("mathProb").innerHTML=firstNum+operator+secondNum+"=";
    rightAnswer=choose1/choose2;
}
}
```

Comment: [Never use parseInt without specifying the radix.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: I'd also suggest to use a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) construct to avoid all those `if (choose==`.

Comment: There's no need to use `parseInt()` here at all.

Comment: @Pointy +1 ... I didn't even looked until that point ^^

Comment: You have not posted anything that shows how you find out what the "rightAnswer" is.  Your "randNum" function operates on numbers and returns a number; there's no need to call `parseInt()` therefore.

Comment: `choose1/choose2` will sometimes be Infinity.

Comment: @dystroy Since Math.random() varies from 0 to 1. In which case choose1 and choose 2 will be Infinity? Just curious to know.

Comment: @Shusl choose2 is an integer in [0, 10].

Comment: I wonder how many `0/0` mentioning answers we get here... Can't blame, though, `NaN`s are nasty - almost as nasty as syntax errors.

Comment: @dystroy Sorry, I misunderstood your statement as you were saying 0/0. I thought you saying choose1 itself is Infinite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `choose==1`, `operator` is misspelled as `oprator`. If you correct it, problem is solved
http://jsfiddle.net/uERwd/2/

**UPDATE:**
Your code can be made shorter as: http://jsfiddle.net/uERwd/3/

Comment: +1 for the only answer mentioning (and solving) the actual problem  AND showing the sensible (DRY) way of doing this task. )

Comment: Thank you a lot. I modified "operator" for the first case, addition. Also, to avoid division by zero, and to have an integer as a result, I modified:                                           else if (choose==4)
 {
 operator="/";
 var choose2=randNum(1,10);
 var choose1=choose2 *randNum(0,10);  ...} I will make my code shorter and DRY. Thank you again sv_in!

Comment: @raina77ow, that is good piece of code, IMO. I just intended to show a quick example on how to reduce JS code

Comment: @LaviniaTomole, raina77ow's code is pretty neat. You can check that to get some more pointers to keep it DRY

Answer (score 3):

Your division operation has the possibility of dividing by zero, which would return NaN.

Comment: No exactly : 1/0 gives Infinity. Only 0/0 gives NaN.

Comment: Well, he has the possibility of getting that too.

Comment: He doesn't output this result, so he clearly wasn't talking about it.

Comment: Thank you a lot. To avoid division by zero, and to have an integer as a result, I modified:                                           else if (choose==4)
 {
 operator="/";
 var choose2=randNum(1,10);
 var choose1=choose2 *randNum(0,10);  ...}

Answer (score 2):

Your "NaN" bug is here :

```
rightAnswer=choose1/choose2;
```

`choose1` an `choose2` are integer in `[0, 1]`.

One time over 121, you're dividing 0 by 0, wich gives `NaN`.

And a little less than one time over 11, you're dividing a not null number by 0, wich gives `Infinity`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify with a number that represent numeral system, tipically, base 10

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Add the number 10 to the function call like this

```
firstNum = parseInt(choose1, 10);
```

Comment: No need to parseInt here, first; no error goes from that misuse here (and will be fixed by that answer), second.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple syntax error:

```
oprator="+"; // should be `operator`
```

That's why this statement...

`firstNum+operator+secondNum+"=";`

... will actually be evaluated as ...

`firstNum+undefined+secondNum+"=";`

The first pair will give you `NaN`, `NaN` + Number will be a `NaN` again, and `NaN` + String (`"="`) will result in `NaN` converted to string, then appended with '=' (hence resulting 'NaN=').

I'd strongly recommend placing `"use strict";` line at the beginning of your scripts to catch such errors. With this, you'll get an error:

`ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable oprator`

... and won't need to make SO parse your script for errors instead. )

Sidenotes, I have plenty of them:

- your `randNum` function will return you a Number, so no need to use `parseInt` (you may have to convert *arguments* of this function, but even that seems not to be necessary here) on its result;
- if you divide by zero, you get `Infinity`; if you divide zero by zero, you get `NaN` as a result; be prepared or adjust the minimums. )
- you violate [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), repeating most of the statements outputting a result, why don't convert them into a function? Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uERwd/4/) snippet (started by @sv_in, completed by me) for example how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

When you randomly choose the division operator, it's possible to have zero come out for both `choose1` and `choose1`, which means you attempt to evaluate `rightAnswer = 0 / 0;`. In Javascript, this equals `NaN`. Additionally, and this should happen more often, if you choose zero in the denominator any other number in the numerator the answer will come out as `Infinity`. Of course, zero over anything is zero.